# Spock test output in application log

Tags: gradle, slf4j, spock, spock-reports

How can I get Spock test execution console output or similar to my application log apart from the consolidated HTML or XML reports?

Using Gradle 2.11 and Slf4j backed by log4j.

Comment: If you run Gradle on the command line, then by default test failures are presented on console. You want something different?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  `gradle test` command to run your tests you can include `--info` and `--debug` switches in your command to run test.

Use something like this to run your tests `gradle --info test` That should log all the info statements on console.

Comment: Wanted to know how to print the same output to application log.

Comment: How exactly do you run your tests now?

Comment: Using Gradle, gradle test